# javascript lookup value of a map object which is array of array

Tags: javascript

I have a JS `map` object (new to JS here) which is an array of array like so:

```
scores=[["key_1",true],["key_2",false],["key_3",false]....["key_n",true]]
```

I am able to access the values on the console like so:

```
scores[0] //outputs ["key_1",true]
scores[0][0] //outputs "key_"
//..and so on.
```

How do I however make a (fast) lookup for a particular key in the object array, something like:

```
scores[["key_3"]] //obviously wont work
//expected output: false
```

Comment: `lookup = new Map(scores); lookup.get('key_3')`

Comment: You also might want to consider using a Set() or an object with attributes if you're simply dealing with key/value pairs.

Comment: @JonTrent A `Map`, as in Patrick's comment, works with arrays of arrays and is as efficient as an object or `Set`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: please post this as an answer and I will accept this. This looks elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to turn the array into an object.

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to change back into array.

```js
var scores = [
  ["key_1", true],
  ["key_2", false],
  ["key_3", false],
  ["key_4", true]
];

scores = Object.fromEntries(scores);

console.log(scores.key_3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `find` the key.

```js
const scores=[ ["key_1",true], ["key_2",false], ["key_3",false], ["key_4",true] ];

var score = scores.find(score => score[0]==="key_3")

console.log(score[0]+" is "+score[1])
```

**Returns:**

```
key_3 is false
```

You could also transform the array-of-arrays to a [Map](https://javascript.info/map-set) object.

To get an easy access to the key-value pairs, while it's still iterable.

```js
const scores=[ ["key_1",true], ["key_2",false],["key_3",false], ["key_4",true] ]

var scoreMap = new Map();
scores.forEach(score => scoreMap.set(score[0], score[1]))
 
console.log("key_4 is "+ scoreMap.get("key_4"))
 
console.log([...scoreMap.keys()])
```

Comment: @LukStroms: For some reason, I like Patrick's answer.. Thoughts?

Comment: @JohnM If you do `console.log(scores)` after it, then you'll notice that his method turned the 2D array into an object.  So if you use that trick, then I would probably use another variable name for it.

Comment: @JohnM I realised that since that array is basically containing key-value pairs, that using find for each key is indeed not optimal. So an alternative was added.